# Kafka Consumer - Java Implementation

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I came across this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example) for implementing the KafkaConsumer in Java.  The below listed code reads the stream and processes the messages. Will this code keep listening to incoming messages once it is started? If so , how do it keep running and keep consuming the messages?

```
public void run(int a_numThreads) {
    Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(a_numThreads));
    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);

    // now launch all the threads
    //
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(a_numThreads);

    // now create an object to consume the messages
    //
    int threadNumber = 0;
    for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {
        executor.submit(new ConsumerTest(stream, threadNumber));
        threadNumber++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why they decided to call it Kafka.

Comment: Kafka has its origins in the Czech language. The meaning of Kafka is 'resembling a bird'. Maybe  a "dove" which passes message from source to destination ;)

Comment: How interesting! I speak Czech a little (very little) and I had no idea, and it's not in my dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will keep listening to incoming message once it is started since it use a [ThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)) (Number of thread in the threadpool = `a_numThreads`) and each of the thread in the threadpool execute a Consumer (`ConsumerTest`).

If you look closely at the `ConsumerTest` class, you'll see that there is an infinite loop. The `it.hasNext()` is blocking (see [ConsumerIterator](https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/consumer/ConsumerIterator.scala)) so the consumer will always wait for the next message :

```
public void run() {
        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
            System.out.println("Thread " + m_threadNumber + ": " + new String(it.next().message()));
        System.out.println("Shutting down Thread: " + m_threadNumber);
}
```

With that said, it is possible to set a timeout with the property `consumer.timeout.ms` that `Throw` a timeout exception to the consumer if no message is available for consumption after a specified interval of time, but the default value is -1 (no timeout) so by default, consumer will always keep consuming messages till the consumer and the executor is shutdown (See the `shutdown` method in the example).

Comment: Thanks Jean! Is the iterator an implementation provided by Kafka which causes the program to block and wait for next message?

Comment: Exactly, the iterator is implemented in Kafka and is backed by a java BlockingQueue. "An iterator that blocks until a value can be read from the supplied queue. The iterator takes a shutdownCommand object which can be added to the queue to trigger a shutdown" (https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/consumer/ConsumerIterator.scala)